# Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew is returning false always even if all cookies are cleared

Tags: xconnect, tracking

Basically, on form submit, I'm trying to store data into contact's Personal Info facet for an **anonymous visitor** who is visiting the website for the **first time** using the code [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/set-contact-facets-in-session.html#idp25323) from the official docs.

As given in the example code, first `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew` is checked for true before creating a contact and storing data into facets. When I visited the website for the first time, `Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew` returned true and a contact was created with data stored into Personal Info facets successfully - I verified this from Experience Profile.

But, when I submitted the form after clearing all the cookies in the same browser to re-check again with another Personal data, the `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew` is returning **false**, which is wrong according to my understanding. Because `Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew` checks whether the contact already exists in xConnect or not. This should be checked by sending the value of `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` to xConnect. Since I have cleared the cookies, how it is still saying that the contact already exists in xConnect by returning false for `Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew`? Doesn't Sitecore identify returning anonymous contacts based on `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE`?

Is this an issue on my side or should I reach out to the Sitecore support? I'm using Sitecore 9.3

Comment: In my dev if I check Contact.IsNew on first page load it is true. Refresh it is false. Clear cookie, it is true again.

Comment: Oh! Are you using Sitecore 9.3? Thanks

Comment: Yes. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ap8okrbqxip89qp/2020-07-27_09-54-24.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Thanks @ChrisAuer! I'll try checking on my side again..

Comment: Though for sometime it was working fine returning true.. occasionally I'm seeing false when I make the first visit. I just faced it in chrome incognito mode.

Comment: Identifiers count is 0, but IsNew is returned as false..??! Should I reach out to Sitecore support?
https://ibb.co/GkCYDRh

Comment: above I've given the link of the screenshot image I took when debugging in Visual Studio.